# Recording data to external storage(android)

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am facing a problem of storing external data into external text file. My code is as below, but it always give me IOException cases. I didn't see any file created in the directory. The apps just close by itself, is it possible to remain it open? why?

```
    private void RecordData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myFile = new File("sdcard/suntrackingdata.txt");
    DataSeq = countDis[9] + "," + yawDis[9] + "," + yawdiffDis[9] + "," + AziIniDis[9] + "," + AziFinDis[9] + "," + AxDis[9] + "," + AyDis[9] + "," + ThetaDis[9] + "," + ThetaDiffDis[9] + "," + yawONEdecDis[9] + "," + yawNONdecDis[9] ;
    //if(myFile.exists() == false)
    //{
    //  myFile.mkdirs();
    //}
    try{
    myFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    osw.append(DataSeq);
    osw.close();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording... ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed to write file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

i got this in logcat when i turned the recording on.

```
    07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/suntrackingdata.txt: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at com.example.suntracking.MainActivity.RecordData(MainActivity.java:536)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at com.example.suntracking.MainActivity.access$4(MainActivity.java:526)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at com.example.suntracking.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:109)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
07-03 22:32:33.068: W/System.err(4764):     ... 13 more
```

My latest code

```
    private void RecordData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    externalPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    myFile = new File(externalPath,"suntrackingdata.txt");
    DataSeq = countDis[9] + "," + yawDis[9] + "," + yawdiffDis[9] + "," + AziIniDis[9] + "," + AziFinDis[9] + "," + AxDis[9] + "," + AyDis[9] + "," + ThetaDis[9] + "," + ThetaDiffDis[9] + "," + yawONEdecDis[9] + "," + yawNONdecDis[9] ;
    /*if(myFile.exists() == false)
    {
        myFile.mkdirs();
    }*/
    try{
    myFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    bw.write(DataSeq);
    bw.close();
    fos.close();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording... ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you added permissions?

Comment: Added, but still the same.

Comment: did you added write permission?

Comment: I added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Is it different? I didn't see something like EXTERNAL_STORE_PERMISSION

Comment: Yes, it's ok. My name was just to say that you need write.

Comment: So, do you see anything wrong with my coding? My apps keep closing after i press the button to activate the data writing function.

Comment: Okay, I have solved the auto close problem. It was my algorithm problem. But i am still having failed to write file problem. Anyone can help?

Comment: Try to print the stacktrace. Log.d(TAG, "EX", e);

Comment: I just added e.printStackTrace() , still the same. sorry i am still new to this.

Comment: Post the Log result to understand why crashes

Comment: What makes you sure that sdcard points to the sd card?

Comment: are you sure the path to sdcard is `sdcard/`, because it depends on devices sometimes it is `mnt/` and sometimes it is `SdCard/` as well

Comment: I use file explorer with root to find it, after device/sdcard

Comment: but first you will have to get into external storage directory using `getExternalStorageDirectory()` you can not just write path to it.

Comment: so i change it to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "filename.txt" ?

Comment: okay wait I will post it as answer that will be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the way you are specifying the path to the file. Below is the code snippet I use to create the file to the external storage directory.

```
//This line gets the path to your external storage directory.
File externalpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//This line is to specify the filename in the above identified directory.
File newfile = new File(externalpath, "example.txt");

//This if condition will check if the file exists or not and will create an empty file if it doesn't exist.
if (!newfile.exists()) {
            newfile.createNewFile();
}

try {
        FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
        BufferedWriter bufferedwrite = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(fileoutputstream));

        //you can write however way you want to write in the file 
        bufferedwrite.write("I am writing this file in the external storage");
        bufferedwrite.close();
        fileoutputstream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IOexception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I got the FileNotFoundException, is it because i originally don't have that file in the folder? or it will automatically create one for me?

Comment: 07-03 22:59:58.086: W/System.err(17884): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/suntrackingdata.txt: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Comment: please check the code again. I have edited it to check for the file

Comment: Now it shows recording, but when i open the txt file, nothing inside. And is there anyway i can make the apps to create the txt file?

Comment: with this code it is creating the file. then you will have to use any of the filewriter or bufferedwriter to write it to the file.

Comment: @user3008754 and what is the data type of `Dataseq` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56721/discussion-between-setu-and-user3008754).

Comment: I added my latest code on top, it works sometimes but sometimes not. Sometimes it will create the file and record the data but sometimes the file not even created.

Comment: file will only be created if it doesn't exists. and as this file is in external storage it will not be deleted on app uninstall. you will have to delete it manually. the code that you updated also works for me so it might be something to do with other part of your code.

Comment: After creating the file once, i deleted it and press on record, the file was not created.

Comment: then what happened? error? exception? file not found toast?

Comment: Nothing happen, it shows Recording but no file was created. The way to solve it is by creating another file with same name. But after that when u wanna delete u have to delete both only another new file will be created. Weird situation..

Comment: I have heard this first time. put this line in `myFile.createNewFile()` if condition as I did and then try again.

Comment: having unhandled exception error with the createnewfile in the condition.